# Why grep returns all output in subprocess stdin?

Tags: python, subprocess

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/home/ubuntuUser$ cat test.txt 
This is a test file
used to validate file handling programs
#pyName: test.txt
this is the last line
ubuntu@ubuntu:/home/ubuntuUser$ cat test.txt | grep "#pyName"
#pyName: test.txt
ubuntu@ubuntu:/home/ubuntuUser$ "

#1  >>> a = subprocess.Popen(['cat test.txt'], 
                             stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                             shell=True)
#2  >>> o, e = a.communicate(input='grep #pyName')
#3  >>> print o
#3  This is a test file
#3  used to validate file handling programs
#3  #pyName: test.txt
#3  this is the last line
#3  
#3  >>>
```

Questions:

Q1: 
shell grep command on a file prints just the matched line, while grep via subprocess prints the whole file. Whats wrong?

Q2: 
How is the input sent through communicate() is added to the 
initial command ('cat test.txt')?
After `#2`, will the initial command be appended by input string from communicate after a "|" and shell command gets like `cat test.txt | grep #pyName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@prasath if you are looking for an example to use communicate(),

```
[root@ichristo_dev]# cat process.py  -- A program that reads stdin for input
#! /usr/bin/python

inp = 0  
while(int(inp) != 10):  
    print "Enter a value: "  
    inp = raw_input()  
    print "Got", inp  


[root@ichristo_dev]# cat communicate.py
#! /usr/bin/python

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE  

p = Popen("./process.py", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)  
o, e = p.communicate("10")  
print o  


[root@ichristo_dev]#./communicate.py  
Enter a value:   
Got 10
```

Comment: Thanks Ignatious. This explains how communicate works. Great.So if the intial command is waiting for an stdin input, command sent via communicate would deliver it to the stdin of that command. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps passing `grep` to the `communicate()` -function does not work as you assume. You could simplify your process by grepping directly from the file as follows:

```
In [14]: a = subprocess.Popen(['grep "#pyName" test.txt'], stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)

In [15]: a.communicate()
Out[15]: ('#pyName: test.txt\n', '')
```

It might be a lot smarter to do what you want to do in python. The following will print your line if it's in the file.

```
In [1]: with open("test.txt") as f:
   ...:     for line in f:
   ...:         if "#pyName" in line:
   ...:            print line
   ...:            break
   ...:         
#pyName: test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! However i'm looking for an example to use communicate("do something")

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is essentially `cat test.txt < grep ...` which is apparently not what you want. To set up a pipeline, you need to start two processes, and connect the stdout of the first one to the stdin of the second:

```
cat = subprocess.Popen(['cat', 'text.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
grep = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '#pyName'], stdin=cat.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, _ = grep.communicate()
print out
```

Comment: thanks. "cat text.txt < grep..." - this answers my questions. So communicate("do something") is "cat text.txt < do something"? Can anyone add an example using communicate("a real shell action") to see how exactly it interacts with the initial command...

Comment: @Prasath: I think you misunderstood my point. `cat < grep` is not correct - it prints a file called "grep". That's not what you're looking for.